# How to show number of available streams using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, osx

I just want to see how many streams are inside my video file.

I looked at the [official documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) and I cannot see what option I can use. Perhaps another command/terminal app can do something similar?

Any ideas how it can be done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have `ffprobe` installed:

```
ffprobe <input> -show_entries format=nb_streams -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1
```

You can also filter for video or audio streams by adding `-select_streams v` or `-select_streams a`, respectively. See [the manual](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) for more details.

If you do not have `ffprobe`, `ffmpeg` can be used too, but in a slightly less robust way (i.e., this may break if the output format changes or something contains the words "Stream #" in the output):

```
ffmpeg -i <input> 2>&1 | grep "Stream #" | wc -l
```

Comment: More direct is `ffprobe input -show_entries format=nb_streams -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1`

Comment: Thanks, post updated, I sometimes forget that there's a format class as well.

Comment: `ffprobe.exe -i "vid.mkv" -show_entries format` gets the job done, I don't know about all those options you listed.

Comment: @Shayan The options I've used ensure that you'll only get one number as output. Your command shows everything.

Comment: For a "smaller" command, we could use another writer: `-of csv=p=0` instead of `-of compact=p=0:nk=1`

Answer (score 0):

To count "*number of available streams using ffmpeg'*":

```
ffmpeg.exe -i %input% 2>&1 | find /c "Stream"
```

Tested in Win 10 CMD